# RTL8723AE wireless needs a better driver, my attempt to fix made it worse

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I have an MSI GE40 laptop with Realtek RTL8723AE wireless card. The driver for it is far from perfect, so I was looking for alternative drivers, and found this: https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver It seemed pretty safe to try as it automatically backs an old driver up, so I went for it. Installation went smoothly without any troubles, but after rebooting there was no wireless option in NM at all. So I decided to get back to kernel driver, and tried both options of getting it back that were mentioned in readme to that driver: restoring the backup with the provided script and reinstalling the original driver with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Tried rebooting after doing that.

But neither of those ways helped, and now I have no wireless. `ifconfig` doesn't show `wlan0` interface.

I guess I am missing something trivial as the original driver has to be in place now, would really appreciate your help.
I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with all updates.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling this driver helped: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

```
make 
sudo make install
```